# Change content on dynamic component angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a ngFor like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let object of objects; let i = index" class="discover__col">
```

with an event binding like thins

```
<a (click)='onOpen(object)'>Details</a>
```

I have a dynamic modal like this.

```
dynamicModal(object): void {
    const modal$ = this.modalService.create(SharedModule,     DynamicModalComponent, {
      title: object.title,
      desc: object.desc  
  }
```

I get tile and desc are undefined.

how can I pass the object that I'm iterating on in the ngFor loop?

ModalService

```
@Injectable()
export class ModalService {
  private vcRef: ViewContainerRef;
  private injector: Injector;
  public activeInstances = 0;

  constructor(private compiler: Compiler) {
  }

  registerViewContainerRef(vcRef: ViewContainerRef): void {
    this.vcRef = vcRef;
  }

  registerInjector(injector: Injector): void {
    this.injector = injector;
  }

  create<T>(module: any, component: any, parameters?: Object): 
Observable<ComponentRef<T>> {
    const componentRef$ = new ReplaySubject();
    this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module)
  .then(factory => {
    const componentFactory = factory.componentFactories.filter(item => item.componentType === component)[0];
    const childInjector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([], this.injector);
    const componentRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(componentFactory, 0, childInjector);
    Object.assign(componentRef.instance, parameters); // pass the @Input parameters to the instance
    this.activeInstances ++;
    componentRef.instance["componentIndex"] = this.activeInstances;
    componentRef.instance["destroy"] = () => {
      this.activeInstances --;
      componentRef.destroy();
    };
    componentRef$.next(componentRef);
    componentRef$.complete();
  });
return <Observable<ComponentRef<T>>> componentRef$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

end service

this is an object `{
        'title':'test',
        'desc':'test2',
    }`

this is the parent

```
    <objects [objects]='objects' (open)='objectModal(object)'></objects>
```

this is child component

```
<div *ngFor='object of objects'>
    <object-component (click)='onOpen(object)'></object-component>
</div>

@Output() open: EventEmitter<Object> = new EventEmitter<Object>();

onOpen(object) {
    this.open.emit(object);
}
```

if I do `title: 'test',
    title: 'test2'`

it works fine.

however, I need to get the info from the ngFor object that was clicked on. basically, I'm not how to pass the info up to the parent, not the index, but the actual object itself. so I can then do this, it not have it be undefined.

```
title: service.title,
title: service.desc,
```

Comment: Can you post the modal service code and does the object have title and desc properties?

Comment: yea, those properties exist

Comment: You have `onOpen(object)` handler yet you are showing the code for `dynamicModal` function. How are they related?

Comment: the onOpen emits the event the triggers the modal. in the event I want to pass the object the was clicked to display the content in the modal.

Comment: Are the title and desc properties on your modal component public? If they are private it will not apply the parameters.

Comment: Also I have a feeling the problem is when you Object.assign() the parameters. In my modal service I pass in the component properties directly `Object.keys(parameters).forEach(key => componentInstance[key] = parameters[key])`. Can you see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Post the stack trace for the error.

Comment: no error just undefined

Comment: actually ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined